# Implementing multiple iterators in same class

Tags: java, iterator, overriding

I was looking back over at some code that I wrote where I'd needed to different iterators, and I noticed that I'd written the first iterator as normal, like this:

```
private class Traverse implements Iterator {
    int pos = 0;
    boolean hasNextCalled = false;
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        hasNextCalled = true;
        if(pos<size()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Card next() {
        return cards.get(pos++);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        if (!hasNextCalled) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("hasNext() must be called before remove()");
        }
        if(pos<1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
       cards.remove(--pos);
       hasNextCalled = false;
    }

}
```

and then implemented the second iterator by creating a new Traverse object but then overriding all the methods:

```
public Iterator OddEvenIterator() {
    Iterator it = new Traverse(){
        private int pos = 0;
        boolean hasNextCalled = false;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            hasNextCalled = true;
            if (pos < size()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Card next() {
            Card nextCard = cards.get(pos);
            pos+=2;
            boolean moreCards = hasNext();
            if(moreCards==false) {
                pos=1;
            }
            return nextCard;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            if (!hasNextCalled) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("hasNext() must be called before remove()");
            }
            if (pos < 1) {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
            pos-=2;
            cards.remove(pos);
            hasNextCalled = false;
        }
    };
    return it;      
}
```

I can't remember why I did this but it feels like a bad way to do it. I was wondering if there was any effective difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second method creates an anonymous class that extends `Traverse`, meaning that you get access to its members (taking into account normal visibility rules, of course). But you then [shadow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) both members that `Traverse` declares, meaning that the anonymous class won't use them.

Given that you define every `Iterator` method and that the return value is typed to `Iterator`, there's no reason to extend a class rather than implementing `Iterator` directly, unless you need access to some members that that class provides. Since you don't in this case, there's no reason to extend `Traverse`.

Furthermore, `Traverse` doesn't define any methods other than the `Iterator` methods, so there wouldn't even be any use in downcasting the iterator returned from `OddEvenIterator` to `Traverse`. If there were, that might be a reason to extend it -- though it would also be a code smell.

The only other reason to extend `Traverse` would be if some other code uses reflection to check for subtypes of `Traverse` (including using `instanceof`). That, again, would probably be code smell -- but it's a possibility.

There are a few stylistic things I'd suggest, btw:

- You should use [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) rather than the raw `Iterator` type
- Most Java conventions have method names start lower-cased (so, `oddEvenIterator()`)
- in `hasNext`, rather than the `if-else`, you can just `return pos < size()`. This is simpler, and always preferable.